# UIPageViewController has wrong UIQueuingScrollView after reload

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

On `UIViewController` I have 2 containers with `UIPageViewControllers`,  each of which has 1 `UIImage`. The Application has a `tabbar`.

- When I load the main `viewcontroller` , every thing is ok. But when I present a new view controller and then dismiss it, I see strange behavior on the second `UIPageViewController`: The `UIView` inside it is placed lower than it should be. When I click on the `UIImage`, it returns to the normal location.
- As I can see in the debugger, the height of `UIQueuingScrollView` of the top and bottom `UIPageViewControllers` not same.
- In the case where I move between `tabbars` everything is ok

What can be wrong? why does the extra space appear after seeing and dismissing a new view controller?

[image: after first loading]
[image: after dismiss new view controller]
[image: debugger]

Comment: what is the mode of the Image?

Comment: Mode of UIView (container) is Scale To Fill , mode of UIImage - Aspect Fit , image have dynamicall height. The value of the image height changes dynamically in code, in contentViewController:      override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        imageHeightLayout.constant = super.view.bounds.height
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: currentProgram.imageName)
        
    }